# Changing email image based on attribute field from a different data extension through a look up

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm extremely new at this but I'm trying to do something similar to this ([How do I use Ampscript in an ExactTarget Template to point to a specific Content Area based on Attribute value?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120028/how-do-i-use-ampscript-in-an-exacttarget-template-to-point-to-a-specific-content/189360#189360)) however the "if@accountID=" value would be a value from a different data table through a look up. So I had this code working which takes the record I am sending to and look them up on a Salesforce Accounts table based on Location_ID__c field. The record which is our customer has that same field and does a look up under the accounts synchronized data extension and pulls in values from the salesforce data extension.

```
%%[

SET @Location_ID__c = AttributeValue("Location_ID__c")
SET @rowset = LookupRows("Account_Salesforce","Location_ID__c", @Location_ID__c)
SET @row = Row(@rowset, 1)]%%



%%= Field(@row, "Type")=%%<br>
%%= Field(@row, "BillingCity")=%%<br>
%%= Field(@row, "BillingState")=%%<br>
%%= Field(@row, "Name")=%%<br>
%%= Field(@row, "Merchant_Industry__c")=%%<br>
%%= Field(@row, "ID")=%%<br>
```

I basically was to change the header based on fields from this look up. So if "Merchant_iIndustry__c" is Furniture I want to change the image. But I need to use the same look up based on Location_Id__c field to determine the industry. Here is what I have and it errors and says "could not find header" which is better than all the errors I was getting before which makes me think I'm closer. Any help would be appreciated.

```
%%[
SET @Location_ID__c = AttributeValue("Location_ID__c")
SET @rowset = LookupRows("Account_Salesforce","Location_ID__c", @Location_ID__c)
SET @row = Row(@rowset, 1)



%%= Field(@row, "Type")=%%<br>
%%= Field(@row, "BillingCity")=%%<br>
%%= Field(@row, "BillingState")=%%<br>
%%= Field(@row, "Name")=%%<br>
%%= Field(@row, "Merchant_Industry__c")=%%<br>
%%= Field(@row, "ID")=%%<br>


/* Template AMPScript <div style="display:none;">*/

var @Merchant_Industry__c, @header
set @Merchant_Industry__c = Field(@row, "Merchant_Industry__c") /* handles null values */

if @Merchant_Industry__c == "Furniture" then

 set @header = ContentAreaByName("Content Builder\Images\Furniture-1.png")

elseif @accountID == "auto parts repair" then

 set @header = ContentAreaByName("Content Builder\Images\Acima_Corp1_EmailHeader.png")

endif

if empty(@header) then
  raiseError("could not find header") /* abort the send */
endif

/*</div>*/

]%%
<!-- (other HTML) -->
```

Comment: Are there any values for the mechanics_industry field? You should set a default value i.e. Case where it's neither of the two. Will cover empties and other values

Comment: Yes I can do that. Good call. Still struggling with the main problem though.

Comment: The main problem is that some of the mechanics_industry fields are null ? Hence why it is catching the error?

Comment: To verify, print the value of `@header` (i.e `%%=v(@header=%%)`)